# How to backup GitLab to the cloud (S3)

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to follow the gitlab [documentation](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/raketasks/backup_restore.md) to upload a backup to the cloud, but I find it sparse, and it isn't exactly straight forward.

Creating the tar is straight forward enough.

My problems start with

> For omnibus packages:

```
gitlab_rails['backup_upload_connection'] = {
  'provider' => 'AWS',
  'region' => 'eu-west-1',
  'aws_access_key_id' => 'AKIAKIAKI',
  'aws_secret_access_key' => 'secret123'
}
gitlab_rails['backup_upload_remote_directory'] = 'my.s3.bucket'
```

What am I supposed to do with this? I place it inside `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml` just so, is that what I do?

```
  multipart_chunk_size:
  encryption:

  gitlab_rails['backup_upload_connection'] = {
    'provider' => 'AWS',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'aws_access_key_id' => 'AKIAKIAKI',
    'aws_secret_access_key' => 'secret123'
  }
  gitlab_rails['backup_upload_remote_directory'] = 'gitlabbackupxan1234'

  ## GitLab Shell settings
  gitlab_shell:
    path: /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/
```

Then we come to

> If you are uploading your backups to S3 you will probably want to
>   create a new IAM user with restricted access rights. To give the
>   upload user access only for uploading backups create the following IAM
>   profile, replacing my.s3.bucket with the name of your bucket:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1412062044000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
    ...
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my.s3.bucket"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Again, how? I started reading about AIM but it is a big topic and I am not quite sure what to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the instructions on http://cloudkul.com/blog/automate-gitlab-backups-within-amazon-s3-bucket/

No you are supposed to place 'backup_upload_connection' and 'backup_upload_remote_directory' settings inside /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb ... you should also uncomment some other settings -- as you can see from the link above. Then you should reconfigure.

You go to IAM -> new User -> create -> Policies -> create user policy -> paste in the policy given -> replace with the name of the s3 bucket you create (2 locations to replace). After the new user step you will get to know the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key.

You should also setup the cron as they describe.